# How do I craft Crossbow Bolts?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I joined the dawn-guard and then I became a vampire. I love to use my crossbow but I don't have any more bolts. I tried to craft them but I couldn't so I upgraded my smithing.  However, they still don't show up in the smithing menu.

How can I make bolts?

Answer (score 11):

### Step 1

Complete the quest [**A New Order**](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:A_New_Order).

### Step 2

Make sure you have the [Steel Smithing](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Smithing) perk & talk to [Sorine Jurard](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Sorine_Jurard).  She should train you in constructing a basic crossbow & steel bolts.

### Step 3

Locate [**Gunmar's Forge**](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Forge#Gunmar.27s_Forge), you'll *need* it to craft most crossbow & bolt recipes in much the same way as the Skyforge is *required* for Nord Hero gear.

**You can now start making bolts**

### Step 4 (Optional)

Complete an [**Ancient Technology**](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Ancient_Technology) quest for Sorine.  Your reward will be plans for either an improved crossbow or exploding bolts.  When you start getting plans for dwarven gear, get the [Dwarven Smithing](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Smithing) perk if you don't already and you plan on using them.

**Repeat Step 4** until you have common & enhanced crossbow recipes and common & 3 elemental bolt recipes, all in both steel & dwarven varieties.

Answer (score 4):

To be able to smith crossbow bolts, you must first finish the [Ancient Technology](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Ancient_Technology) quest. To start this quest, [A New Order](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/A_New_Order) must be completed, and you must talk to Sorine Jurard.

Answer (score 0):

You can not craft crossbows or bolts if you have gone the vampire route in the dawngaurd dlc. The quests everyone is mentioning and sorrine are only if you go dawngaurd and refuse Harkins gift of becoming a vampire lord.